# How to get count of days?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to count the total days in between two dates( including start date and end date).

**Code :**

```
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStart.Text);
DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEnd.Text);
TimeSpan datedifference = end.Subtract(start);
int dateCount = datedifference.Days;
```

From the above code I getting the difference between two dates.

**Example :**

**Current Output:**

```
start= 10/25/2015
end= 10/25/2015
dateCount=0

OR

start=10/25/2015
end=10/26/2015
dateCount=1
```

**Required Output :**

```
start= 10/25/2015
end= 10/25/2015
dateCount=1

OR

start=10/25/2015
end=10/26/2015
dateCount=2
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Reshama You can find the difference between time and divide that by 24 that will give correct difference to you. Thanks

Comment: @HenkHolterman - if not specified differently: yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStart.Text);
DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEnd.Text);
TimeSpan datedifference = end.Subtract(start);
int dateCount = datedifference.Days + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int dateCount = datedifference.Days + 1 ;
```